# Targeting two separate elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an spinner element made from two spans for + and - and an text input element in the middle that shows the quantity selected from the increase and decrease:

```
<div class="quantity-spinner"> 
 <span class="input-number-decrement">–</span><input class="input-number" type="text" value="1" min="0" max="10"><span class="input-number-increment">+</
</div>
```

I have two instances of this element, but currently when increasing the quantity for one of the elements it also controls the other one. 
My question is, how can I separate the two elements, so that they are controller independently.

Here is my JavaScript:

```js
(function() {
  window.inputNumber = function(el) {
    var min = el.attr('min') || false;
    var max = el.attr('max') || false;
    var els = {};
    els.dec = el.prev();
    els.inc = el.next();
    el.each(function() {
      init($(this));
    });
    function init(el) {
      els.dec.on('click', decrement);
      els.inc.on('click', increment);
      function decrement() {
        var value = el[0].value;
        value--;
        if(!min || value >= min) {
          el[0].value = value;
        }
      }
      function increment() {
        var value = el[0].value;
        value++;
        if(!max || value <= max) {
          el[0].value = value++;
        }
      }
    }
  };
})();
inputNumber($('.input-number'));
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The event handlers will be invoked such that `this` will reference the DOM element involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing

```
els.dec.on('click', decrement);
els.inc.on('click', increment);
```

by

```
el.prev().on('click', decrement);
el.next().on('click', increment);
```

you bug comes from the fact that els.dec and els.inc contain 
predecessors and successors for both counters